# How to rotate the camera 90 degrees to the right?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying everything, this should be simple... Any suggestions?

```
viewer.getCamera().rotation.y = 90 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD;
```

I`ve also tried:

```
   const angle = 90;
   const theta = angle * Math.PI / 180;
   var axis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1);
   const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(posX, theta);
   targetVector.setX(targetVector.x + 45);
   targetVector.applyMatrix4(matrix);
   viewer.navigation.setTarget(targetVector);
```

That does something, but I don`t know how to control the proper angle to rotate the camera (and that does not rotate on the X... it seems to rotate Y and X... And nothing close to 90 degrees.

Trying this:

```
const angle = 90;
const theta = 5* angle * (Math.PI / 180);
var posX = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0).normalize();
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(posX, theta);
targetVector.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
viewer.navigation.setView(positionVector, targetVector);
```

The camera goes a little to the right (10 degrees maybe?)... But it also goes a little up (2 degrees maybe).

That is what I want, basically now I just need to go ONLY 90 degrees to the direction I want.

Any thoughts?

Making clear what I want to do...
The image bellow represents the viewing fostrum of the camera looking from above:

[image: Zero degrees camera]

Now lets rotate the camera 90 degrees to the right, and see how the fostrum works...

[image: 90 degrees to right]

The UP vector IS THE SAME ON BOTH CASES.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setCameraUpVector` to apply roll/rotation otherwise your settings would get overridden by  Viewer's custom adaption of THREE's camera (`unifiedCamera`) if you operate directly on the camera object:

```
NOP_VIEWER.navigation.setCameraUpVector(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,  angle * Math.PI / 180))
```

**EDIT**

Below should cover all movements including pitch/roll/yaw - adjust the code to your needs (*`left/right/up/down` are not exactly the precise terms to describe these movements and may cause confusion*)

```
const axis = new THREE.Vector3(0 or 1, 0 or 1, 0 or 1); // x,y,z
const angle = degree * Math.PI / 180;
const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(axis, angle);

const upVec = viewer.navigation.getCameraUpVector();
const pos = viewer.navigation.getPosition();
pos.applyMatrix4(matrix);
upVec.applyMatrix4(matrix);
viewer.navigation.setView(pos, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
viewer.navigation.setCameraUpVector(upVec);
```

Comment: Yes, I`m able to rotate the upVector, but I also need to make the camera go to the LEFT or RIGHT, also, UP and DOWN. So how do I do That?
Thanks Bryan! I hope you can help me with that.